# ASP.Net Core XUnit Integration Testing when Two Factor Authenication is enabled

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I've developing an Angular web application using ASP.Net Core 3.1 for the API.

So far, I've written some integration unit tests using a Custom WebApplicationFactory to create the test server.

All tests use the HttpClient to make GETs and POSTs to the API running under the Custom WebApplicationFactory. Most of these tests initially perform a login to obtain a token to use for subsequent requests.

I'd like to add Two Factor Authentication to the application, but this will inevitably break any tests, as they aren't able to get hold of the six digit code which would be sent via email.

Here is what a test currently looks like, without MFA being implemented.
Is there a way that the test can be given the MFA code so that it can continue to perform tests?

Do I simply need to seed a user that does not have MFA enabled?
I actually want all users to have MFA enabled in production.

Many thanks

```
using Xunit;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyCompany.ViewModels.Authentication;
using MyCompany.StaffPortal.Tests.Shared;
using StaffPortal;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using MyCompany.ServiceA.ViewModels;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace MyCompany.Tests.StaffPortal.ServiceA
{
    public class ExtensionsControllerTests : TestBase
    {
        public ExtensionsControllerTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory) : base(factory)
        {
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Test_GetExtensions()
        {
            //This line creates a new "web browser" and uses the login details provided to obtain and set up the token so that we can request information about an account.
            HttpClient httpClient = await CreateAuthenticatedHttpClient("abcltd1@MyCompany.com", "test", 1);

            //Perform any work and get the information from the API
            //Contact the API using the token so check that it works
            var getExtensionsResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("/api/ServiceA/extensions/GetExtensions");

            //Check that the response was OK
            Assert.True(getExtensionsResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, "GetExtensions did not return an OK result.");

            //Get and Convert the Content we received into a List of ServiceAExtensionViewModel, as that is what GetExtensions sends back to the browser.
            var getExtensionsResponseContent = await getExtensionsResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            List<ServiceAExtensionViewModel> extensionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ServiceAExtensionViewModel>>(getExtensionsResponseContent);


            //Check the information received matches our expectations
            Assert.True(extensionList.Count == 2);
            Assert.True(extensionList[0].PropertyA == 123);
            Assert.True(extensionList[0].PropertyB == 0161);
            Assert.True(extensionList[0].PropertyC == true);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the content's of CreateAuthenticatedHttpClient() for reference.

```
protected async Task<HttpClient> CreateAuthenticatedHttpClient(string username, string password, int companyAccountId)
        {
            var httpClient = _factory.CreateClient(
                new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
                {
                    AllowAutoRedirect = false
                });

            //Create the Login information to send to the server
            var loginInformation = new LoginRequestModel
            {
                Username = username,
                Password = password,
                ReturnUrl = ""
            };

            //Convert it into Json which the server will understand
            var validLoginRequestJson = ConvertToJson(loginInformation);

            //Send the Json Login information to the server, and put the response we receive into loginResponse
            //In the code below, httpClient is like a web browser. You give it the 
            var loginResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("/api/authenticate", validLoginRequestJson);

            //Check the loginResponse was a CREATED response, which means that the token was made
            Assert.True(loginResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created, "New Token was not returned.");

            //Check the response is identified as being in Json format
            Assert.Equal("application/json; charset=utf-8", loginResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());

            //Next we have to convert the received Json information into whatever we are expecting.
            //In this case, we are expecting a AuthenticationResponseViewModel (because that's what the API sends back to the person trying to log in)
            //First we get hold of the Content (which is in Json format)
            var responseJsonString = await loginResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            //Second we convert the Json back into a real AuthenticationResponseViewModel
            AuthenticationResponseViewModel authenticationResponseViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthenticationResponseViewModel>(responseJsonString);

            //Now we take the Token from AuthenticationResponseViewModel, and add it into the httpClient so that we can check the Token works.
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResponseViewModel.token);

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CompanyId", companyAccountId.ToString());

            return httpClient;
        }
```